# IPC::Open2 middleware

Tags: perl, stdin

I would like to make a wrapper that would take data from STDIN and pass it to another script, wait for his STDOUT response and output it to STDOUT on the parent side.

I have the following code but it does not seems to work:

```
test.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
use IPC::Open2;
$pid = open2( \*RDR, \*WTR, '/usr/bin/perl test2.pl');

while (<STDIN>) {
     print WTR; 
}

while (<RDR>) {
     print STDOUT;
}
```

and on the test2.pl, i have:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#

while (<STDIN>) {
     print STDOUT;
}
```

It seems to write to test2.pl but i have no feedback from test2.pl.

Any hints?

Thank's,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should `close WTR` when you are done reading from `STDIN`. Your external command will keep expecting input until you do this, and if you are suffering from buffering, your external program won't terminate and it won't output anything.
2. You are probably ["suffering from buffering"](http://www.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html) in <strike>both your primary script and in</strike> your external command. 
   In your test script, you can add `$|=1` to the top of the script to make its output more responsive. You might not be able to affect the output buffering of an arbitrary external command, though.

Update: `IPC::Open2` already sets autoflush on the write filehandle, so the external command won't be starved for input.

Comment: As mob pointed out adding a $|=1 to the child process will do the trick. Note that you have to close the stdin of the parent process to allow it getting out from the first loop (on unix it's enough to press ctrl-d)